# HttpInterceptor after rxjs pipeable operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors

is it possible to intercept a HttpClient get request after the execution of some pipeable operators of rxjs. In my case, I have an auto-generated http service which transforms the blob responses to objects. My global error interceptor needs to transforms the blobs too, because it triggers before the pipeable operators in the service.

PseudoCode-Example:

My request somewhere:

```
this.httpClient.get('api/something')
               .pipe(map(x => ({modified: true})))
               .subscribe();
```

My HttpClient interceptor:

```
intercept(req, next) {
    return next.handle(req)
               .pipe(tap(x => {console.log(x);})); 
}
```

Desired behavior:
The console.log should output my modified object from the map operator. It seems like the interceptor is always the first part in the chain.

My question:
Is it possible to achieve my desired output?

BR

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem? we are facing the exact same problem with our NSwag generated TS client

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I kept my workaround solution.

Comment: what was your work around?

Comment: duplication of code because I can't reuse the auto generated private blob reader function

Answer (score 0):

We actually ended up creating a function to convert the blob to something useful:

TypeScript:

```
    private transformBlobToJson = (
        response: HttpResponseBase
      ): Promise<string> => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          const responseBlob =
            response instanceof HttpResponse
              ? response.body
              : (<any>response).error instanceof Blob
              ? (<any>response).error
              : undefined;
          blobToText(responseBlob)
            .pipe(
              map(responseText => {
                if (responseText !== null) {
                  const responseObject: ICustomResponseModel = JSON.parse(
                    responseText
                  );
                  return responseObject.message
                    ? responseObject.message
                    : responseObject.title;
                }
                return null;
              })
            )
            .subscribe(res => {
              return resolve(res);
            });
        });
    }

    function blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
      return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
        if (!blob) {
          observer.next('');
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = event => {
            observer.next((<any>event.target).result);
            observer.complete();
          };
          reader.readAsText(blob);
        }
      });
    }
```